# How can I publish a post with two or more authors?

Tags: author

A friend and I have a Wordpress blog and we want to be able to publish a post with more than one author. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can try out the [Co-Authors Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/co-authors-plus/) plugin. You will need to edit your theme template files to see multiple authors.

Comment: Good answer. Worth noting this plugin is more actively updated and managed by Automattic employees (employees for WordPress.com).

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Posts-2-Users

Answer (score -1):

I have used this before and it works great: [Multiple Authors](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-authors/)

Comment: This plugin has not been updated since 2006 and is self-described as "obsolete".